# Bad input warning in python

Tags: python, input

The question for the code is attached below .

Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:

X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475

Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output as shown below. Do not use the sum() function or a variable named sum in your solution.

You can download the sample data at http://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt when you are testing below enter mbox-short.txt as the file name.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname,'r')
count=0
val=0
for line in fh:
    if line.find("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")==-1:
        continue
    else:
        count+=1
        pos=line.find(':')
        val+=float(line[pos+1:]
res=float(val/count)
print('Average spam confidence: ',res) 
fh.close()
```

I am getting an error stating "bad input on line 13".
can anyone help me out as to why this is happening? Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post the *exact*  error message. Note that your code as shown includes a typo (``val+=float(line[pos+1:]`` should be ``val+=float(line[pos+1:])``) – it cannot throw any error other than ``SyntaxError``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parentheses. It should be "val+=float(line[pos+1:])"

Answer (score 1):

The code below works (with the text example you have provided)

```
import requests

total = 0
cnt = 0
r = requests.get('https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt')
if r.status_code == 200:
    lines = r.text.split('\n')
    length = len('X-DSPAM-Confidence:')
    for line in lines:
        idx = line.find('X-DSPAM-Confidence:')
        if idx != -1:
            cnt += 1
            val = float(line[length + 1:])
            total += val
res = float(total / cnt)
print('Average spam confidence: ', res)
```